# What's the splat doing here?

Tags: ruby, splat

```
match, text, number = *"foobar 123".match(/([A-z]*) ([0-9]*)/)
```

I know this is doing some kind of regular expression match but what role does the splat play here and is there a way to do this without the splat so it's less confusing?

Comment: Which splat?  There are three in your example.

Comment: shoover: are you sure? If you mean the `[A-z]*` and `[0-9]*` then they're not splats - they're part of the regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way to do this without the splat so it's less confusing?

Since `a,b = [c,d]` is the same as `a,b = *[c,d]` and splat calls `to_a` on its operand when it's not an array you could simply call to_a explicitly and not need the splat:

```
match, text, number = "foobar 123".match(/([A-z]*) ([0-9]*)/).to_a
```

Don't know whether that's less confusing, but it's splatless.

Answer (score 5):

The splat is decomposing the regex match results (a `MatchData` with three groups: the whole pattern, the letters, and the numbers) into three variables. So we end up with:

```
match = "foobar 123"
text = "foobar"
number = "123"
```

Without the splat, there'd only be the one result (the `MatchData`) so Ruby wouldn't know how to assign it to the three separate variables.

Answer (score 3):

There's a good explanation in the [documentation for MatchData](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html#M001276):

> Because to_a is called when expanding
>   *variable, there‘s a useful assignment shortcut for extracting matched
>   fields. This is slightly slower than
>   accessing the fields directly (as an
>   intermediate array is generated).
>
> ```
>    all,f1,f2,f3 = *(/(.)(.)(\d+)(\d)/.match("THX1138."))
>    all   #=> "HX1138"
>    f1    #=> "H"
>    f2    #=> "X"
>    f3    #=> "113"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

String.match returns a MatchData object, which contains all the matches of the regular expression. The splat operator splits this object and returns all the matches separately.

If you just run

```
"foobar 123".match(/([A-z]*) ([0-9]*)/)
```

in irb, you can see the MatchData object, with the matches collected.

Answer (score 0):

MatchData is a special variable, for all intents and purposes an array (kind of) so you can in fact do this as well:

```
match, text, number = "foobar 123".match(/([A-z]*) ([0-9]*)/)[0..2]
```

[Learn more about the special variable MatchData](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html)

Comment: It's a class, not a variable (well technically it's a constant pointing to a class, but so are String, Array etc) and there's nothing special about it. You can call `[]` on a MatchData instance because it defines `[]` and you can use the splat operator on it because it defines `to_a`.