# passing an unknown number of Arguments to a ruby function

Tags: ruby, syntax

I'm writing a method to wrap another method as part of a class. It needs to both take and pass on an arbitrary number of arguments.

Something like...

```
def do(*things)
  old_method(things)
end
```

except this won't work because old_method needs to be passed the contents of the things array as separate arguments rather than as an array.

I just can't think of a way to do this within ruby syntax...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
def do(*things)
  old_method(*things)
end
```

That's a splat operator, see e.g. [What does the (unary) * operator do in this Ruby code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918449/what-is-the-operator-doing-to-this-string-in-ruby) or  [What's the splat doing here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456146/whats-the-splat-doing-here)

Answer (score 1):

Same way you get the arguments, `old_method(*things)`.